# MySQL datetime CASE

Tags: mysql, datetime, case

I have problem with my `datetime` field and `CASE` function. I have stored users' last action timestamp and I want to create a view which shows me that user is online if last action is in last 5 minutes.

However, my function isn't working and I'm needing your help. This is what I've tried.

```
SELECT 
CASE a.lastAction
WHEN >= (NOW() - INTERVAL 5 MINUTE) THEN
    1
ELSE
    0
END AS 'online'
FROM
    users a
```

Sample datetime data from users table: 2015-12-22 22:43:01

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query returns an error because you're using the `>=` operator. You should check the [case syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/case.html). The value of the `WHEN` clause should be an expression.

So, you should use this approach:

```
SELECT 
CASE 
WHEN a.lastAction >= (NOW() - INTERVAL 5 MINUTE) THEN
    1
ELSE
    0
END AS 'online'
FROM
    users a
```

I simply moved the `a.lastAction` in the `WHEN` clause - you may note that there are two ways of writing a CASE block in MySQL:

```
CASE case_value
    WHEN when_value THEN statement_list
    [WHEN when_value THEN statement_list] ...
    [ELSE statement_list]
END CASE
```

or

```
CASE
    WHEN search_condition THEN statement_list
    [WHEN search_condition THEN statement_list] ...
    [ELSE statement_list]
END CASE
```

You should have used the second one.

Comment: Good answer! Thank you very much.